# Using JavaScript to wait until an image exists in the server?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in JavaScript alone you can wait until an image file exists on the server?

For a better explanation of my current situation users can press a button to get an image rendered but as of now they have to refresh for it to load. I wanted a better way to do this by deleting the previous image and then waited until a new one existed on the server which at that point it would show the new Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any way for the server to notify the client that the image is ready, you could poll for the image with a simple fetch.

```
fetch('https://example.com/some-image.jpg', {
  method: 'HEAD'
}).then((res) => {
  if (res.ok) {
    // Your image is ready
  }
});
```

Do that every 5 or 10 seconds, or whatever is appropriate for your use case.